# Java HashMap - Checking a certain value

Tags: java, hashmap

Consider I have a HashMap like the below example:

```
private static Map<String, Double, Integer, Integer> Items = new HashMap<>();
    // item name Price CurrentStock, Minimum Stock
    Items.put("Chocolate", 1.35, 13, 11 );
```

How would I make it check if the 13 is the 11 or below~?  Is this possible with HashMaps, if not what should I do?

Comment: oops.... this program won't even compile. you need to study some basic tutorial about what is map and how to use it. what is map?

Comment: You cannot have a Map like that. Map has key value pairs. You can have HashMap<String,Integer> or HashMap<Object,Object>. Please learn about collections before trying to use them

Comment: Sorry, I quickly wrote it up and kind off in a hurry, forget the item name   Just use :::

private static Map<Integer, Integer> Test = new HashMap<>();
Test.put(13, 11);

How would I check if that 13 is below that 11    if so   do something

Comment: Also sorry, I'm relatively new to Java and trying to learn how to use HashMaps for a personal project

Answer (score 1):

Maps have only a key and a value. You can use `Map<KeyType,List<ValueType>>`

For example

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.Add(1.35);
list.Add(13);
list.Add(11);
map.Add("Chocolate",list);
```

And then check

```
List<Integer> chocolate = map.get("Chocolate");    
if (chocolate.get(1) < chocolate.get(2)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out now, is the get(1) part   13     and get(2)   11?   I'll be buying a java book soon so will learn at a better pace :)

Comment: Exactly, take a look at the edit i've made